# Replace 0s of jTextField as I type

Tags: java, netbeans, jtextfield

I want jTextField with 12 0s and I need to change those 0s to numbers I type as I type.

- In begining there is 000000000000
- If I type 123 then it should be 000000000123

I done this on `KeyPressed` event, but it's not working properly.

```
  try {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
        jTextField1.setText(String.format("%012d", i));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        jTextField1.setText(String.format("%012d", 0));
    }
}
```

It changes as I type, but there is few problems.

1. It changes till I type 11 numbers, just after I type 12th number it delete all numbers and it display again as 000000000005 (if 12th number I typed is 5)
2. When I delete all it shows only 10 0s not 12,but When I type a number again it shows typed number and 11 0s.

Any solutions?

Comment: what did you mean **it's not working properly.**

Comment: `not working properly.` What is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: I added those on quection just now. sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a custom class that tries to simulate data entry of a bank machine. That is text is entered right to left:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.text.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class ABMTextField extends JTextField
{
    private DecimalFormat format;
    private String decimal;

    public ABMTextField(DecimalFormat format)
    {
        this.format = format;

        decimal = Character.toString( format.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator() );

        setColumns( format.toPattern().length() );
        setHorizontalAlignment(JFormattedTextField.TRAILING);

        setText( format.format(0.0) );

        AbstractDocument doc = (AbstractDocument)getDocument();
        doc.setDocumentFilter( new ABMFilter() );
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String text)
    {
        Number number = format.parse(text, new ParsePosition(0));

        if (number != null)
            super.setText( text );
    }

    public class ABMFilter extends DocumentFilter
    {
        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offs, String str, AttributeSet a)
            throws BadLocationException
        {
            replace(fb, offs, 0, str, a);
        }

        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offs, int length, String str, AttributeSet a)
            throws BadLocationException
        {
            if (".0123456789".contains(str))
            {
                Document doc = fb.getDocument();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()) );

                int decimalOffset = sb.indexOf( decimal );

                if (decimalOffset != -1)
                {
                    sb.deleteCharAt(decimalOffset);
                    sb.insert(decimalOffset + 1, decimal);
                }

                sb.append(str);

                try
                {
                    String text = format.format( format.parse( sb.toString() ) );
                    super.replace(fb, 0, doc.getLength(), text, a);
                }
                catch(ParseException e) {}
            }
            else
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }

        public void remove(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length)
            throws BadLocationException
        {
            Document doc = fb.getDocument();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()) );

            int decimalOffset = sb.indexOf( decimal );

            if (decimalOffset != -1)
            {
                sb.deleteCharAt(decimalOffset);
                sb.insert(decimalOffset - 1, decimal);
            }

            sb.deleteCharAt( sb.length() - 1) ;

            try
            {
                String text = format.format( format.parse( sb.toString() ) );
                super.replace(fb, 0, doc.getLength(), text, null);
            }
            catch(ParseException e) {}
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
//      DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");
        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0000000000");
        ABMTextField abm = new ABMTextField( format );

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add( abm );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ABMTextField");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( panel );
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can change the default mask as follows:

```
//DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0000000000");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String result = text.substring(1) + inputKey;
```

this will exclude the left character and add the new one.

Comment: this will rotate your output value, always keeping the text.length and removing the left character.

Answer (score 0):

Your integer values may be maxing out, try just using the String.

```
    try {
        String i = jTextField1.getText();
        String text = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < (12 - i.length()); j++) {
            text += "0";
        }
        jTextField1.setText(text + i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        jTextField1.setText(String.format("%012d", 0));
    }
```

Or if you would like it even shorter, you could do this.

```
    try {
        String i = jTextField1.getText();
        String text = "000000000000";
        jTextField1.setText(text.substring(0, (12-i.length())) + i );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        jTextField1.setText(String.format("%012d", 0));
    }
```

Which just substrings a String of 12 0's depending not he length of the text field, and then adds it to the end.

Comment: It is **only 1 text field** not two. I did mistake when I type the code here first time.

Comment: I fixed it for you

Comment: It only changed the 12th character. Rest 0s stays 0s. if i type 1,2,3 it dispaly 000000000003